# Terminal command "rails server"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash

My terminal does not return to the usual command line prompt `$` after I run `rails server`.  If I open another Bash window everything works fine.

Should I just exit the first window, or will I interrupt some process?

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: show the screen-shot,, so that we can see it...

Comment: Hi, you have to have 15 reputation points to post images, which I do not :(

Comment: Are you sure that you want to do "rails server" vs "rails console" to get a command prompt?

Comment: Use http://postimage.org/ for that... there are always workarounds.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes when you use `rails server` or `rails s` the `WEBrick` server starts and keeps running it in the terminal tab you ran it on(till you interrupt it).

In Terminal `Ctrl + C` is used to `kill/break/interrupt` any process only

`$` not showing means there is a process already running in that terminal and therefore you have to open a new terminal tab(`Ctrl + Shift + T`) and work there or break the existing ongoing process to get the `$` and work in the present tab.

This also might help you out

http://help.codeschool.com/discussions/rails-for-zombies-2/225-after-i-enter-rails-server-on-the-command-line-the-command-line-doesnt-reappear

In other words you ideally can't or actually shouldn't use the terminal in which the server is running on, but anyways if you DO want to then this SO thread should help you

[How to use same terminal window after using "rails server" command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955196/how-to-use-same-terminal-window-after-using-rails-server-command)

Hope you understood

Answer (score 4):

If you run `rails server` or `rails s`, you wouldn't get that prompt. You need to press `Ctrl-C` to shutdown the server. That instruction is present is command shell itself (`=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server`).

```
(arup~>sample_app)$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-01-27 02:22:02] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-01-27 02:22:02] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-02-24) [i686-linux]
[2014-01-27 02:22:02] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=11223
```

Now see below, what happened when I did press **Ctrl-C** :

```
(arup~>sample_app)$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-01-27 02:22:02] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-01-27 02:22:02] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-02-24) [i686-linux]
[2014-01-27 02:22:02] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=11223 port=3000
^C[2014-01-27 02:24:59] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2014-01-27 02:24:59] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
Exiting
(arup~>sample_app)$
```

Comment: Thanks Arup. I'm trying to set up my first_app from Learning Rails Tutorial. Will CTRL-C mess up that process?

Answer (score 0):

use:

> rails server -d

to start the server as daemon.